# Deck of cards, trouble with inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, class-design

I am having a problem with inheritance.

Basically I am trying to teach myself object oriented programming and I can't get my enum array to use the `toString` method I have created for it. Instead it is using the one from the `PlayingCards` class.

How do I fix this?

```
public class PlayingCards {

private final Rank rank;
private final Suit suit;

 /**
 * Creates enums for rank
 */
 public static enum Rank {

    ACE(1),
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9),
    TEN(10),
    JACK(11),
    QUEEN(12),
    KING(13);
    private int rank;

    private Rank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

}

/**
 * Creates enums for suit
 */
public static enum Suit {

    HEARTS(14),
    SPADES(15),
    CLUBS(16),
    DIAMONDS(17);
    private int suit;

    private Suit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}

/**
 * Constructs a card with specified initial rank and suit
 *
 * @param rank sets rank to ACE by default
 * @param suit sets suit to SPADES by default
 */
public PlayingCards(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[Rank = " + this.rank
            + ", Suit = " + this.suit + "]" + "\n";
}

public String format() {
    return this.rank + " of " + this.suit;
}

/**
 * Tests whether this card is equal to some other card.
 *
 * @param otherObject the card to be tested.
 * @param rank imports enums rank
 * @param suit imports enums suit
 * @return returns true if the suit and rank of test card is equal to the
 * suit and rank of this card otherwise false is returned.
 */
public boolean equals(Object otherObject, Rank rank, Suit suit) {
    if (otherObject == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    PlayingCards other = (PlayingCards) otherObject;
    return suit == other.suit && rank == other.rank;
}

}
```

This section is where I am having problems. It is creating the array fine but it's just displaying it in the compiler using the `toString` method from the wrong class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pack extends PlayingCards
{
 static PlayingCards[] card = new PlayingCards[52];
 PlayingCards.Suit[] suit2 = PlayingCards.Suit.values();
 PlayingCards.Rank[] rank2 =  PlayingCards.Rank.values();
 private int numberOfCards;
 /**
 * Constructs a pack of 52 cards.
 * Sorted by suit Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades.
 * Sorted ascending.
 * @param rank
 * @param suit
 */  
 public Pack(Rank rank, Suit suit)
 {
 super(rank,suit);
    card = new PlayingCards[52];
    numberOfCards = 0;
    for ( int x = 0; x < suit2.length; x++ )
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < rank2.length;y++ )
        {

            card [numberOfCards] = new PlayingCards(rank2[y],suit2[x]);
            numberOfCards ++;
        }
    }
}

/**
* Shuffles cards in pack.
*/
 public void shuffle()
 {
 }

/**
* @return string representation of 52 card pack.
*/

@Override
public String toString() {
String toString = "New pack\n";
    for (int cards =0; cards < card.length; cards++)
    {
        toString = toString + card[cards] + "\n";
    }
    return toString;
}
}
```

This is what I get. The result has been formatted using the wrong `toString` method:

```
 assed3.PlayingCards[Rank = ACE, Suit = HEARTS]
 , assed3.PlayingCards[Rank = TWO, Suit = HEARTS]
 , assed3.PlayingCards[Rank = THREE, Suit = HEARTS]
 , assed3.PlayingCards[Rank = FOUR, Suit = HEARTS]
 , assed3.PlayingCards[Rank = FIVE, Suit = HEARTS]
```

Comment: Can you break your code to separate the section where you encounter problems (and add what you are expecting) from the rest of the class definition (maybe remove total irrelevant code)

Answer (score 2):

Problems/errors in your code:

- **Naming.** The class `PlayingCards` should be renamed as `PlayingCard`. An instance of this class will represent **one** playing card, not many. You want to name your classes with names that represent the objects they are modelling in the real world. This avoids confusion when programming with these classes and makes code more intuitive.
- **[Is-a relationship between superclass and subclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)**. A deck of cards **is not** a playing card. You are wrong to let the `Deck` class inherit from the `PlayingCard` class, it makes no sense at all. A deck of cards **is composed of** playing cards. In this case, drop the inheritance relationship between `Deck` and `PlayingCard`.

If you apply these two, your problem will likely be solved already.

---

Other remarks:

- The equals method should be overriden from [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). The equals method you have now in the `PlayingCards` class doesn't make any sense. The easiest way to implement an override is to ask your IDE to generate an implementation for you. When you work in Eclipse for instance, you can ask it to generate it for you. In almost all cases the provided implementation will be OK.
- Whenever you have overriden `equals`, you should generally (read: always) also override [`Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29): equal objects must have equal hash codes. You can usually also ask your IDE to provide an implementation for you.
- When you override a method from the superclass, always add the `@Override` annotation to the method. This will clearly signal that the method is an override. This may not be super important for an override of `Object.toString` because everyone knows that method, but in other classes for different methods it makes code reviewing a lot easier. A method with an `@Override` annotation **is most definitely** an override. A method without that annotation might be or might not be, depending on the superclass. A method that doesn't override a method in the superclass with the `@Override` annotation will result in a compiler error. The more clarity, the better.
- Having the suit represented by an integer is silly. Have the suit represented by a `String`: "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamans", "Spades".
- Having `PlayingCards.Suit[] suit2` and `PlayingCards.Rank[] rank2` as members of the `Deck` class is a waste of memory. If you want to assign ranks or suits to your `PlayingCards[] card` member, use `PlayingCards.Suit.values()` and `PlayingCards.Rank.values()` directly in your constructor.
- `int numberOfCards` is a member variable you use in the constructor as a loop variable. You should not declare this as a member, but should declare it as a local variable in your constructor. That is not to say that you can't have a member representing the total number of cards in the deck, but you shouldn't use it as a loop variable.
- You append `\n` to strings for newlines, but some operating systems expect `\r\n` for line separators. You can get the proper line separator for the OS you are running on using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.
- Building strings is best done using the [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class. The way you construct the string in `toString` representing the deck, creates a new `String` in each iteration. That way of working consumes a lot of memory and trashes the heap leading to fragmentation.
- In your class setup now, with `Deck` deriving from `PlayingCards` you are incorrectly assuming that when `PlayingCards.toString` is called from the `Deck.toString` implementation, that the `getClass().getName()` will return the class name for class `Deck`. At least that's what I think you are expecting. Since you are calling `PlayingCards.toString` on a `PlayingCards` instance, `getClass().getName()` will return `PlayingCards` prepended by the package name.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I have preformed the changes you have suggested but I am still having the error.

Comment: @RyanWard That is because your understanding of the matter is wrong. See the last bullet. The output is correct, your expectation is wrong. Note that you only extremely rarely have to concern yourself with class names, most definitely not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> i can't get my enum array to use the toString method

You should say exactly what is happening. Usually this sort of bug can be diagnosed using your debugger but one problem you have is

```
for (int cards =0; cards <=card.length; cards++)
```

which should be

```
for (int cards =0; cards < card.length; cards++)
```

and if this is the case, you would be getting an error showing what the problem is and exactly which line has the error.